# How to handle a global service for different views in angular?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my scenario. I want to refresh my captcha if the form get error message. And I have multi views to use the captcha.

So I write a factory:

```
Services.factory 'Captcha', ['$rootScope', ($rootScope) ->
  service = {}
  service.new_captcha = () ->
    console.log 'render cap'
    $rootScope.captcha_src = "/captcha?action=captcha&i=#{+new Date}"
  service
]
```

And then another factory where handle the $http process will trigger the code below

```
$http
.error (data) ->
  service.signin_err_msg = data.error
  Captcha.new_captcha()
  $rootScope.$broadcast('new_captcha')
```

In the view controller, $scope value will listen to the broadcast and change the src value.

```
SignUpCtrl = App.controller 'SignUpCtrl', ($scope, UserService, $location, $rootScope) ->

  $scope.UserService = UserService

  $scope.$on 'new_captcha', (val) ->
    $scope.captcha_src = $rootScope.captcha_src

  $scope.captcha_src = $rootScope.captcha_src
```

This works. But I dont think this is a good way. I have to write the same code to listen the rootScope broadcast. Is there same method better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `$rootScope` or to broadcast any events.  This would also work:

**Captcha Service**

```
Services.factory('Captcha', [function() {
  var captchaSrc;
  return {
     get_captcha_src: function() {
       if (!captchaSrc) {
         this.refresh_captcha();
       }
       return captchaSrc;
     },
     refresh_captcha: function() {
       captchaSrc = "/captcha?action=captcha&i=" + new Date();
     }
  }
}]);
```

**HTTP Handler**

```
$http.error(function(data) {
  service.signin_err_msg = data.error;
  Captcha.refresh_captcha();
});
```

**Controller**

```
var SignUpCtrl = App.controller('SignUpCtrl', function($scope, $location, UserService, Captcha) {
  ...

  $scope.get_captcha_src = function() {
    return Captcha.get_captcha_src();
  }

  // or this: $scope.get_captcha_src = Captcha.get_captcha_src;

});
```

Comment: This works. But I dont know why the `$http` works as well. I dont think they get the same `Captcha`. But it really works.

Comment: Angular services are singletons within the application.

Answer (score 1):

As rtcherry says, you don't need to use `$rootScope`.
Please have a look at this Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/4ppfCi/preview